# Find number of prime numbers between 2 and n

Tags: python, primes

I am trying to find the number of prime numbers between 2 and n, where n is provided by the user. I can't seem to make it work. here's my code:

```
>>> def numOfPrime(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2,n):
        p = True
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j ==0:
                p = False
    if  p == True:
        count += 1

    return count

>>> numOfPrime(100)
0
```

Comment: The algorithm is quite inefficient. You could use a sieve method or, at the very least, in the inner loop first check if the number is even and then do trial division by the odd numbers which are less than the square root of `i`. At the very,very least make the inner loop a while loop which stops as soon as a factor is found. When you get to `i= 98`, for example -- you know that it isn't a prime as soon as you divide it by `j=2`, but your code nevertheless does completely pointless checks for `j = 3,4,...,97`

Comment: right, I will work on it.

Comment: What you have is a good start if you are just learning Python, but at some stage you need to concentrate on the underlying algorithm. Good luck. Post another question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation of your `if` block is incorrect. It should be in the loop.

```
def numOfPrime(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2,n):
        p = True
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j ==0:
                p = False
        if  p == True:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Now `numOfPrime(100)` returns 25, which correctly accounts for 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, and 97.